# textalyser functionality using Python

Tags: python, text-analysis

Which Python based library is out that gives the text-analysis functionality similar to the http://textalyser.net/

Answer (score 1):

Depends which statistics you want, but this seems like a good start, and includes "readability" statistics like textalyser does:
http://www.koders.com/python/fidA751A0C03B16B06781096ED2C89E2B7621FE4BCB.aspx?s=cdef%3Acrawler

It uses another module called textanalyzer which will do some of the other things seen on textalyser directly.

Comment: textanalyzer seems to be providing the basic code (in combination with nltk) for basic statistical processing of text data.